# Unable to import maven project in IntelliJ14

Tags: maven-3, intellij-14

I'm trying to import the Maven projects from IntelliJ button (the one with the arrows in circle), but I get the following message "Unable to import maven project. See logs for details", as shown in the following picture

[image]

If I go into the log, I see:

```
2015-06-01 11:16:46,932 [  89176]  ERROR -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - org/apache/maven/execution/MavenExecutionRequestPopulationException 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/maven/execution/MavenExecutionRequestPopulationException
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.Maven32ServerImpl.applyProfiles(Maven32ServerImpl.java:81)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:556)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:811)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:670)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.maven.execution.MavenExecutionRequestPopulationException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 16 more
2015-06-01 11:16:46,933 [  89177]  ERROR -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.3  Build #IU-141.1010.3 
2015-06-01 11:16:46,933 [  89177]  ERROR -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - JDK: 1.7.0_71 
2015-06-01 11:16:46,933 [  89177]  ERROR -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 
2015-06-01 11:16:46,933 [  89177]  ERROR -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - Vendor: Oracle Corporation 
2015-06-01 11:16:46,933 [  89177]  ERROR -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - OS: Linux 
2015-06-01 11:16:46,933 [  89177]  ERROR -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - Last Action: Maven.Reimport
```

I'm using Maven 3.3.3 and JDK 1.7.0_71 on a 64bit Ubuntu machine.

Strange thing, is that I can use Maven by command line. Any idea?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Below one worked for me ;

Go to *File > Settings > Build,Execution,Deployment> Build Tools > Maven > Importing* .

Change **VM options for importer** to **-Didea.maven3.use.compat.resolver**

Comment: This worked for me without deleting anything or going to the extreme.  Try this first.

Comment: @orkn_akgl,
Thanks.. this worked.. just curious to know what was the issue and how does this resolution work.. can you pls elaborate a bit.. thanks : )

Comment: Welcome @BhavukMathur. I actually read some articles about this case before on some website(maybe Intellij website) and I played with that a little bit

Comment: just if someone want to recover default value: `-Xmx768m`

Comment: I did this setting and it was working fine. Then it started again failing so I removed this option and it is working fine for me.

Answer (score 34):

Solved. I had to remove the IntelliJ project folder (`.idea`) and create a new project from the existing source clicking on the parent pom. Then, everything worked properly.

I guess that some file was corrupted.

---

**In steps.**
Initially you have something like:

[image]

After deleting the .idea folder you will have:
[image]

So you close the project and start one from existing sources:
[image]

You select the pom.xml file to create the new project and oveeride the IntelliJ project if one was found.
[image]

Now you should see exactly the same as in the first picture.

Comment: Can you clarify "clicking on the parent pom"? My project is made up of several maven projects. When I import as maven, I always get the error. When I import from source, it does not fail but it does not treat it as maven either.

Comment: This is close to the correct answer for those using intelliJ 15.  Thank you :)

Comment: The answer showing how to change vm options was the better solution. Don't do this unless the other one fails

Answer (score 8):

I had IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2 and maven 3.6.3 couldn't work. So I updated IntelliJ IDEA to a version 2019.3 and could use maven 3.6.3.

Comment: Exactly this was my bug. No one noticed this except U. Thank you much.

Comment: I confirm! IntelliJ 2018.1 is not compatible with maven 3.6.3. I solved downgrading to maven 3.6.1.  (Didn't want to upgrade the licence of IntelliJ)

Comment: that was my problem

Comment: Ermal is right. Also 2018.2  is not compatible with maven 3.6.3, nor 2.6.2 so downgrade it straight to 3.6.1 and hopefully you will be ok.

Comment: Downgrading maven to 3.6.1 for intellij version 2018.3 ,worked.

Comment: @ABHISHEKBHARDWAJ Yes, of course, but I didn't want to downgrade :)

Answer (score 7):

I don't know what caused this, all i know it was very easy to fix:

1. Download maven [here](https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi) and extract it in a place of your choice.
2. Then, go to `File`>`Settings`>`Build, Execution, Deployment`>`Build
       Tools`>`Maven`.
3. In `Maven home directory`, instead of Bundled maven, point it to the
       folder you just created.
4. Enjoy.

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me

1. Go to: `File > Settings > Build,Execution,Deployment > Build Tools >
       Maven > Importing`
2. Change: `JDK for importer` to your **installed JDK**
       instead of IDEA's internal JRE (`Use Internal JRE` from
       `../JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA/jre64`)

Also searching in IDEA log files helped me. I found this message:

> Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3.2\jre64\bin\java" (in directory "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3.2\bin"): CreateProcess error=2, File not found

Answer (score 3):

In my case I'd just upgraded my OS (OSX) and doing so deleted my JDK, so Intellij was quietly failing. Following @JeanValjean's advice meant that the project was no longer loadable at all (I couldn't get to JVM preferences). Looking in `~/Library/Logs/IntelliJIdeaXX/idea.log` told me the problem and deleting `~/Library/Caches/IntelliJIdeaXX` and `~/Library/Preferences/IntelliJIdeaXX/options/jdk.table.xml` let me open the project again and fix the path to the JDK.

Answer (score 3):

Below is the solution that works the best for me:

Go to File > Settings > Build,Execution,Deployment> Build Tools > Maven > Importing :

Change VM options for importer to **-Xmx4096m**

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was my firewall. I use bullguard protection btw, which is pretty strict with its firewall.

Answer (score 1):

I got into this same state (unable to import maven project) several times (i was running a load test and hitting the max number of open files on the OS, so normal file saves were erroring out).  It probably is a corrupt file causing this.  A computer reboot acutally solved it a few times but other times I solved it by switching to command line and running "mvn clean install"

Answer (score 0):

For me updating it to intellij 2020 worked from 2017.3.

I had tried almost all the solutions described here, but updating intellij to 2020 just worked without doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

Besides all solutions above, you can try close and reimport the project from IDEA. My issue solved by this simple way.