# Maven IntelliJ error: Unable to import maven project. See logs for details

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I am working on Maven based project on IntelliJ idea 2016.3.4, and on adding dependencies, I receive the following error.

```
Unable to import maven project: See logs for details.
```

The idea.log file contains the following logs repeatedly:

```
role: org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.ArtifactResolver
roleHint: ide 
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException: 
java.util.NoSuchElementException
  role: org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.ArtifactResolver
roleHint: ide
at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.Maven3ServerEmbedderImpl.getComponent(Maven3ServerEmbedderImpl.java:475)
at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.Maven3ServerEmbedderImpl.customizeComponents(Maven3ServerEmbedderImpl.java:552)
at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.Maven3ServerEmbedderImpl.customize(Maven3ServerEmbedderImpl.java:529)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:573)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:834)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:688)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:687)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:276)
at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:253)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:162)
at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:227)
at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:179)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy125.customize(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteUtil.invokeRemote(RemoteUtil.java:169)
at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteUtil.access$300(RemoteUtil.java:36)
at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteUtil$2$1$1.compute(RemoteUtil.java:150)
at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteUtil.executeWithClassLoader(RemoteUtil.java:226)
at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteUtil$2$1.invoke(RemoteUtil.java:147)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy125.customize(Unknown Source)
at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenEmbedderWrapper.doCustomize(MavenEmbedderWrapper.java:103)
at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenEmbedderWrapper.access$000(MavenEmbedderWrapper.java:38)
at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenEmbedderWrapper$2.execute(MavenEmbedderWrapper.java:69)
at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.RemoteObjectWrapper.perform(RemoteObjectWrapper.java:76)
at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenEmbedderWrapper.customizeForResolve(MavenEmbedderWrapper.java:66)
at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsTree.resolve(MavenProjectsTree.java:1253)
at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsProcessorResolvingTask.perform(MavenProjectsProcessorResolvingTask.java:44)
at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsProcessor.doProcessPendingTasks(MavenProjectsProcessor.java:130)
at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsProcessor.access$000(MavenProjectsProcessor.java:30)
at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsProcessor$2.run(MavenProjectsProcessor.java:105)
at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.utils.MavenUtil.lambda$runInBackground$5(MavenUtil.java:458)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$2.run(ApplicationImpl.java:309)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException: 
java.util.NoSuchElementException
  role: org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.ArtifactResolver
roleHint: ide
at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:267)
at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:243)
at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.Maven3ServerEmbedderImpl.getComponent(Maven3ServerEmbedderImpl.java:472)
at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.Maven3ServerEmbedderImpl.customizeComponents(Maven3ServerEmbedderImpl.java:552)
at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.Maven3ServerEmbedderImpl.customize(Maven3ServerEmbedderImpl.java:529)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:573)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:834)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:688)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:687)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.Collections$EmptyIterator.next(Collections.java:4189)
at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
... 21 more
2018-11-15 18:32:37,925 [ 379691]  ERROR -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - 
 IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.4  Build #IU-163.12024.16 
2018-11-15 18:32:37,925 [ 379691]  ERROR -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - JDK: 1.8.0_112-release 
 2018-11-15 18:32:37,925 [ 379691]  ERROR -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - VM: OpenJDK Server VM 
 2018-11-15 18:32:37,925 [ 379691]  ERROR -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o 
2018-11-15 18:32:37,925 [ 379691]  ERROR -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - OS: Windows 10 
2018-11-15 18:32:37,925 [ 379691]  ERROR -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - Last 
Action: EditorPaste
```

I tried creating new project and solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30569909/unable-to-import-maven-project-in-intellij14).

But I still get the same error.

Any way to solve this problem?

Comment: Did you delete the .idea project folder before you re import it as a maven project?

Comment: Have you tried running a `mvn` command for the project with the `-X` flag? It may reveal more information about the failure.

Comment: you should attach your pom.xml too

Answer (score 14, accepted):

try to use a new version of maven, i was having the same issue, i changed the maven version of my IDE and the error is gone.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

In my case this error was due to the fact that in the project directory there was a maven wrapper file mvnw and due to the wrapper settings in Intellj Idea it was failing . I Manually went under path Intellj --> Preferences --> Build Tools --> Maven and there after selected a maven version instead of wrapper and this fixed the error .  Detailed screen shot is below .

[image: Intellj idea --> Maven wrapper]

Answer (score 2):

I removed the .idea folder from the project directory and reimported the project. The issue went away.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try to update your idea

When I update 2019.2.1 to 2019.2.4 and the problem is solved by itself and don't forget to choose that maven version in the `build & execution` in intellij.

Answer (score 0):

Could you put here the dependency code that you wrote ?
Your pom might not be well formed 
btw you should have something like that in your pom:

```
 <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <!--<your dependecy>-->
            <groupId></groupId>
            <artifactId></artifactId>
            <version></version>
            <!--<your dependecy>-->
        </dependency>
        ...other dependencies....
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

I also see some lookup erros that can be solved by maven-compat plugin :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compat</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.5</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Your problem might also be generated by your code the `NoSuchElementException` happens when you try to do the next of an `Object` or element and ther's not 
Check your cycles.
I can't tell much more it would be nice to see the code and the pom.

Answer (score 0):

For me, spring 2.6.x and maven 3.6.x worked. Other configurations just didn't work for me.